# What's a good PHP permission framework that allows listing resources?

Tags: php, frameworks, roles, acl

I'm building a new application and I need a permission framework to go along with it.
Here's a quick example of one of the things we need it to support:

With the data model:

```
user
----
id
role
type

resource
----
id
name
type
```

We want to be able to set up an access rule that says a user may only know about all resources with the same type as them, unless they have a role of admin (in which case they can see everything). And then we want to be able to pull a searchable/pageable list of "All resources this user knows about". (Let's say there's 500,000 resources.)

I tried to shoe-horn this into Zend_acl, but while I think I can define all the rules in zend_acl, it's on a resource-by-resource basis, and there's no proper support for getting a *list* of resources out of it, and certainly not in a memory-friendly way (such as showing 10 resources at a time and paging).

So what is a good PHP permission framework that supports relationship-based rules (as opposed to lists) such as these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370371/recommend-a-php-acl-class.

Comment: I'd argue no because I believe an ACL does not meet my needs. Unless I'm missing a way to shoe-horn it in there, I need a rule-based system instead of a discrete-list based system.

I'm open to suggestions on how to achieve my goal within an ACL such as zend_acl. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might still be able to use an ACL, provided that it can be extended to suit your purposes. For instance, Zend_Acl allows you to [write your own ACL assertions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html#zend.acl.advanced.assertions) that can be used to override the resource-based behaviour. You could also extend Zend_Acl to provide the list of all resources available to that user.

Comment: The goal is to get away from hard-coding permission rules, and instead have them defined in a user-modifiable system such as a DB. I suppose I could design something via assertions that ran a particular hard-coded check based on a ACL permission, but it sounds like a fair bit of planning would still need to go into that, and I'd rather rely on a well tested framework.

Comment: Sorry, Christmas break distracted me. Re-reading this, I don't believe zend_acl answers my base question. How can I _LIST_ resources that meet specific assertions? I'm certainly not going to load all resources then run a ACL check against each one to build that list. You mention extending Zend_Acl, but I have been unable to find any hints as to an approach, so my question remains unanswered.

Comment: We have this capability in our extension to Zend_Acl. The ACL is maintained in a database. When the listing is required we go and query the database. Though I see that this does not answer your original question; we had to implement the features you require.